# Import data through VBA from webpage

Tags: json, vba, excel

The following [link](http://www.screener.in/company/?q=526523) has a button as "Export to Excel". When clicked, it downloads an Excel sheet with details for the particular stock.

I want to get this downloaded excel file through Excel VBA, where I have a set of links it loops through them download books from each link, copy certain data and paste it. While writing the code I realised that for downloading from web, the link should end with xlsx or csv or something related to excel.

```
Sub transfercsv()
sLink = "http://www.screener.in/company/?q=500095" 'I can loop and attach links to this..
sfile = "downloaded.xls" 'I can get this rectified as well...
ssheet = "Data sheet" 
'Further code I can build up
....
End sub
```

Final question: "How can I ask Excel VBA to download the workbook behind the Export to Excel link."

or

"How can I find the xlsx link behind the Export to Excel button."

P.S:- I have tagged as JSON as well, becasuse while researching I found the the export link has something to do with JSON..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Pratyush from Screener.in.

The above won't work because of these technical reasons:

1. The export function uses POST request.
2. The page is behind a user login.
3. The post request has CSRF protection to prevent automation.

This has been done because generating customized XLSX files is heavy and server dynamic process, and being on a shared host we have limited resources.

A better alternative can be to use Google Docs worksheets. They have a wonderful API integrated with Google Finance which can provide much of the financial data.

Comment: Thanks Pratyush...... Im googling your words as well...if you can guide me to any links for the same...

Comment: You can try these links: https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pzLh3kFGO3Cw_nZZVZj0_HA&output=html&gid=0&single=true and http://www.labnol.org/internet/import-html-in-google-docs/28125/